# What's wrong with my ponytail palm

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, palm

My neighbor moved across the country and gave me this palm along with a few other plants and starts. I really know absolutely nothing about them. The condition that they are in now are the condition they were in when they were given to me two weeks ago.

The second picture is the middle of the plant that had a thick hard type of something that was covering the whole part but I took small pieces off curious as to what it was I hope I didn't hurt it. Any help Is greatly appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Debnsteve,   There is no way from that picture and with no real history to tell you what went wrong.    I can tell you that the middle part is where it was pruned at one point to force the plant to create multiple branches.  In other words it's an old wound that was intentionally done for aesthetics reasons, but did not hurt the tree.     I want to give you some advice on what to do now, but first I need to know more about your location in the world.  You can start by removing any dead leaves, leaves that have zero green.   I will wait to hear back from you to give you more details.

Comment: The second photo is out of focus - it might be a Begonia, but can you repost a clear picture please. As for the ponytail palm, is the bulbous, bottom part of the stem soft and soggy, or just shrivelled and dry? Does the pot its in have drainage  holes?

Comment: Hello again, I forgot to mention, the black stuff in picture 2 is a coating they paint on a plant after they make a large cut.  It will come off naturally with time.  For now just leave it and let it fall off on its own